# CLI Linux with "shred" command

Tags: linux, command-line, shred

I am trying to find an OS that I can boot from my USB stick without further installation. I tried Tinycore but sadly I just couldnt save the Package "Coreutils" on it, so I had to reinstall it everytime I reboot the system. It is important that I can use the "shred" command. Because the USBsticks only purpose will be to shred old PCs. Also I dont want to connect the PCs to network. Pretty much just boot from the usb and type the command. I prefer Command line only, because a GUI is just not necessary.
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to consider [DBAN](https://dban.org/)

Comment: You seem to be running live versions only. Do a proper OS install onto the USB and then you may also permanently install programs.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/). It works very well